# Using Qt in a pre-existing x-platform project?

Tags: windows, macos, qt, cross-platform

I have an existing cross platform project that runs on Mac, Linux and Windows.

Now, I want to add a 'native' UI to it - the ability to show some popup windows (to request user credentials) and perhaps FileOpen dialogs. By native I mean I want to use the systems build in file-open dialog - so on the Mac the mac file finder is shown and on Windows the shells file open window is shown.

Qt seems a good fit - its samples show that it can show the correct dialog on all platforms.

However, all the available Qt samples start at the very base level - assuming the entire project is developed in Qt. Is it possible to initialize and use Qt in a more ad-hoc fashion :- i want to keep all my Qt UI code in a seperate dll/dylib/so file with some simple exports (think ShowLoginPopup).

Answer (score 1):

I think that the easiest approach would be to do it the other way around - having the Qt GUI drive the rest of the application. Qt is event based and does rely on its event loop, so you need to keep that running.

Comment: that is really not an option. The app already has an event loop and refactoring that now would be a huge pita. When combining multiple frameworks that all insist on their own event loops - perhaps I could run Qt on a thread. I don't know though how even loops work on OSs other than windows.

Comment: @Chris Becke... The Qt code gets upset if its UI code is not running on the main (first) thread in a program.  However, it does work well in a threaded environment besides that.

Comment: what event loop is your app running? Qt is compatible with the glib event loop. Otherwise, you could thread it as cjhuitt says.

Have you considered a client/server architecture with an XML RPC or DBUS connection between two separate clients?